# json.loads() always throws a valueerror regardless of json input

Tags: json

One of my test cases is trying to  validate some json using the following:

```
CONFIG = '../reconnoitre/config.json'

print(is_json(CONFIG))

# return true is json is valid or false if unable to load
def is_json(json_file):
  try:
    json_object = json.loads(json_file)
  except ValueError:
    return False
  return True
```

Regardless of what JSON I pass this the routine always returns false, for example:

```
{
  "test": "test"
}
```

Will still return a false value. Given the simplicity of the function - is there a better way I can validate if a file is valid json or not?

Comment: Try `json.load()` or json with multiple data. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.loads` will try to evaluate its argument as json, but you gave it the filename, which of course is no valid json. Load the content into a string instead, and pass that to `json.loads`, or even better, use `json.load` inside a `with open(...)` block.

Comment: That... makes a lot of sense. Not sure why I presumed that it would open the file for me, late night coding!

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't work either, tried ```json_object = json.loads(str(open(json_file, 'r')))```

Comment: try: `with open(json_file, "r") as f: json_object = json.load(f)`

Comment: Or alternatively, it would be `with open(json_file, "r") as f: json_str = f.readall()` and then `json_str` passed to the `loads` method.

Comment: AH! That's the ticket. Thankyou!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd also like it if there was a `json.loadf` method which would work the way you've initially tried it. The `with open()` around the call to `load` seems very boilerplate-ish / repetitive.